# Can I create a List of maps with multiple puts from a list of numbers?

Tags: java-8

I have some working code that I would very much like to refactor...

```
List<Map<String, Object>> refactor = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<>();
List<BigDecimal> listOfAmounts = Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal("1.10"), new BigDecimal("2.20"), new BigDecimal("3.30") );

for ( BigDecimal bd : listOfAmounts ) {
    temp.put( "name", "Randolf Smith" );
    temp.put( "amount", bd.toString() );
    refactor.add( temp );
}
```

This will provide something like

```
"refactor": [  { "name": "Randolf Smith", "amount": "1.10" } { "name":
"Randolf Smith", "amount": "2.20" } { "name": "Randolf Smith",
"amount": "3.30" } ]
```

which is what is required but I would very much like to do this with streaming but can't seem to get a hold of how I would manage it.

```
listOfAmounts.forEach( a ->
    {
        temp.put( "name", name );
        temp.put( "amount", a.toString() );
    } 
    refactor.add( temp ); 
);
```

was a first attempt which I haven't really tested (would need tweaking) as it still involves declaring the map and list variables.

so I suppose I'm wondering if there is a way to do it along these lines

```
listOfAmounts.stream.collect(Collectors.toMap("amount", bigDecimal -> bigDecimal.toString()) )
```

but as you can probably see from the half-hearted line I'm not really even sure where to start ?  Can anyone help ?

Comment: `listOfAmounts.stream().map(bd->{
                    HashMap<String,Object> m = new HashMap<>(); m.put("name","Randolf Smith");m.put("amount",bd);return m;
                }) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: That's great thanks.  I was wondering if there was some amazing way to do it without any declarations but this is good.  Thanks.  Put it in an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` operation to convert each element of `listOfAmounts` to `HashMap` and collect them into a list.

```
listOfAmounts.stream()
            .map(bd -> {
                Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
                m.put("name", "Randolf Smith");
                m.put("amount", bd);
                return m;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or even like this:

```
listOfAmounts.stream()
           .collect(ArrayList::new, (l, b) -> {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name", "Randolf Smith");
                map.put("amount", b);
                l.add(map);
           }, List::addAll);
```